# Is there an issue with Haskell GHC 8.4.3 on Travis?

Tags: haskell, travis-ci

My [Travis builds](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/jobs/388291576) are failing when they attempt to install using the nightly resolver (since 8.4.3) with:

```
$ stack --resolver $RESOLVER --no-terminal --install-ghc test --only-dependencies
Selected resolver: nightly-2018-06-05
Downloading nightly-2018-06-05 build plan ...
Downloaded nightly-2018-06-05 build plan.
Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Preparing to download ghc-8.4.3 ...
ghc-8.4.3: download has begun
ghc-8.4.3:   15.21 MiB / 144.83 MiB ( 10.50%) downloaded...
ghc-8.4.3:   37.85 MiB / 144.83 MiB ( 26.13%) downloaded...
ghc-8.4.3:   61.16 MiB / 144.83 MiB ( 42.23%) downloaded...
ghc-8.4.3:   76.60 MiB / 144.83 MiB ( 52.89%) downloaded...
ghc-8.4.3:   91.49 MiB / 144.83 MiB ( 63.17%) downloaded...
ghc-8.4.3:  115.03 MiB / 144.83 MiB ( 79.42%) downloaded...
ghc-8.4.3:  138.27 MiB / 144.83 MiB ( 95.47%) downloaded...
ghc-8.4.3:  144.83 MiB / 144.83 MiB (100.00%) downloaded...
Downloaded ghc-8.4.3.
Unpacking GHC into /home/travis/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.3.temp/ ...
Configuring GHC ...
Installing GHC ...
Received ExitFailure 2 when running
Raw command: /usr/bin/make install
Run from: /home/travis/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.3.temp/ghc-8.4.3/
The command "stack --resolver $RESOLVER --no-terminal --install-ghc test --only-dependencies" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

When run with `--verbose` this command produces the final lines

```
2018-06-13 13:52:53.964026: [debug] "utils/ghc-cabal/dist-install/build/tmp/ghc-cabal-bindist" copy compiler stage2 "strip" '' '/home/travis/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.3' '/home/travis/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.3/lib/ghc-8.4.3' '/home/travis/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.3/share/doc/ghc-8.4.3/html/libraries' 'v p dyn'
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-06-13 13:52:57.445300: [debug] Installing library in /home/travis/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.3/lib/ghc-8.4.3/ghc-8.4.3
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-06-13 13:53:08.362061: [debug] strip:/home/travis/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.3/lib/ghc-8.4.3/ghc-
8.4.3/stFVIxC7: No space left on device
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-06-13 13:53:08.442841: [debug] make[1]: *** [install_packages] Error 1
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-06-13 13:53:08.443962: [debug] make: *** [install] Error 2
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
Received ExitFailure 2 when running
Raw command: /usr/bin/make install
Run from: /home/travis/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.3.temp/ghc-8.4.3/
The command "stack --resolver $RESOLVER --no-terminal --install-ghc test --only-dependencies --verbose" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

Is there [a problem with 8.4.3 on Travis](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/15239#ticket)?

---

Relevant `.travis.yml`:

```
sudo: false

language: generic

cache:
  directories:
  - "$HOME/.stack"

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - libgmp-dev

env:
# ... several working resolvers
- $RESOLVER="nightly"

before_install:
# Download and unpack the stack executable -- https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/travis_ci/?highlight=travis
- mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
- export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
- travis_retry curl -L https://www.stackage.org/stack/linux-x86_64 | tar xz --wildcards --strip-components=1 -C ~/.local/bin '*/stack'

install:
# Build dependencies
- stack --resolver $RESOLVER --no-terminal --install-ghc test --only-dependencies --verbose

script:
# Build the package, its tests, and its docs and run the tests
- stack --resolver $RESOLVER --no-terminal --install-ghc test --haddock --no-haddock-deps
# List components explicitly; ignoring failure
- stack --resolver $RESOLVER exec ghc-pkg list || true

notifications:
  webhooks:
    urls:
      - https://webhooks.gitter.im/e/33a1859c14283f0dbab6
    on_success: change
    on_failure: always
    on_start: never
```

Comment: Fwiw, I'm using GHC 8.4.3 on Travis CI w/o any problems via https://github.com/haskell-CI/haskell-ci

Comment: @hvr Hmmm. Do you see the same paths as above?

Comment: This is a question for GHC devs, not SO community. Try GHC mail-lists or IRC.

Comment: @orome Can you try adding `--verbose` to the Stack command to get a little more information about what's failing?

Comment: FYI, I just noticed an example of a Travis job of mine using GHC 8.4.3 and succeeding: https://travis-ci.org/yesodweb/yesod/jobs/391306911

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman: Added output from `--verbose`.

Comment: "strip:/home/travis/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.3/lib/ghc-8.4.3/ghc-
8.4.3/stFVIxC7: No space left on device" I'd try clearing the cache and rebuilding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving to an answer from the comments: the issue is that Travis has run out of disk space. This can be observed by passing the `--verbose` flag to Stack. My recommendation is to clear the cache and try again.

I've also opened up [a Stack issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4085) to improve the output in this case.